# scala weird symbol "_@" meaning

Tags: scala, lift-json

I am wondering what this scala symbol is: `_@`.

(Search engines have trouble with weird characters so it's hard to find anything on google...)

Here is the context:

```
def doNodeParse(json: JValue): TreeNode = {
    json match {
        case JObject(List(JField("Condition", JObject(List(JField("var", JString(variableName)), JField("Operation", JString("LT")), JField("Value", JDouble(threshold))))),
                JField("onTrue", _@ onTrue),
                JField("onFalse", _@ onFalse),
                JField("onMissing", _@ onMissing)
                )) =>
                LessThanNode(variableName, threshold, doNodeParse(onTrue), doNodeParse(onFalse), doNodeParse(onMissing))

        case _ => {
            throw new Error("failed parsing json!")
          }
    }
}
```

(The types of `onTrue`, `onFalse`, `onMissing` are `JsonAST.JValue`)

Comment: http://symbolhound.com/?q=_%40 ?

Comment: There is no `_@` symbol, but not spaced symbols `_` and `@` (pattern alias)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's legal to omit the space between `_` and `@` in a pattern match, so in this case it's the same as

```
    case JObject(List(JField("Condition", JObject(List(JField("var", JString(variableName)), JField("Operation", JString("LT")), JField("Value", JDouble(threshold))))),
            JField("onTrue", _ @ onTrue),
            JField("onFalse", _ @ onFalse),
            JField("onMissing", _ @ onMissing)
            )) =>
            LessThanNode(variableName, threshold, doNodeParse(onTrue), doNodeParse(onFalse), doNodeParse(onMissing))
```

The effect of the @ operator is to alias the value matched on the left to the name on the right for the match.

Comment: Oh, it's in a pattern match! The line was soooooooo long I thought it was in a method call.

Comment: so is `_` a variable being thrown away then?  I am confused why you would make an alias just to throw it away... why not just do ` JField("onTrue",  onTrue)` instead?

Comment: The normalized form is actually the other way around, `onTrue @ _` etc, that is, what you see in `-Xprint:typer`. I use it to disable `-Ywarn-unused:patvars`